# my hp 15s fq2643tu(i5 11 gen windows 11) laptop keeps showing this "one of your disks is at risk(smart event)" how should i resolve this?

Tags: windows-11, hp

[image]

This notification keeps coming and if I click it, it says "intel optane memory and storage management file origin: hard disk on this computer" and it wants permission to make changes on my device.

I've tried clicking both yes and no several times but it still keeps coming.

Comment: See if Intel has a Diagnostic App to test the optane disk

Comment: Back up your data now.

Comment: Have you verified the disk's health using an appropriate tool? [Edit] your question to include the necessary information to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) to examine
the SMART data of all your disks.

If you find a disk for which Speccy will give a bad status, or that
some of the disk's SMART attributes are not marked as "Good",
this is most likely the disk that is the cause of these messages.

Once you find the disk, backup immediately its data and replace by a new
disk.

If you wish to have our opinion,
[Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1755963/edit)
your post and add a screenshot of the SMART attributes of this disk.

Comment: Backup everything first, then start digging deeper. More likely than not OP's computer has exactly one drive. Even if it's a false alarm, nobody ever got hurt by having an extra copy of their valuable data.